# how to display constantly random numbers tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How to display random numbers in canvas that the number changes constantly.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange
from tkinter.font import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
while True:
    var=randrange(0,10)
    var+=60
cv = Canvas(root,width=200,height=200,bg="blue")
styles = Font(family="calibri",size=30,weight="bold")
cv.create_text(100,100,text="Number: "+str(var),font=styles,fill="lightblue")
cv.pack(side=RIGHT)
root.mainloop()
```

I want the efect of random nums lile in this code, but in tkinter canvas

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep
from os import system

while True:
    system("cls")
    rand = randrange(10)
    rand+=60
    print("Random number: ",rand)
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example, that uses `randint` and `after()`.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
#from tkinter.font import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")


def repeat():
    global timer
    rand = random.randint(1, 100)
    # configuring the tag, to overcome over writing of text.
    cv.itemconfigure('rand', text="Number: "+str(rand))
    # asking to repeat it, you can change the interval.
    timer = root.after(1000, repeat)

def stop():
    root.after_cancel(timer)

cv = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg="blue")
#styles = Font(family="calibri",size=30,weight="bold")
cv.create_text(100, 100, font=("calibri", 20, "bold"),
               fill="lightblue", tag='rand')  # added a tag
cv.pack()

b_start = Button(root, text='Start', command=repeat,width=10)
b_start.pack(pady=10)

b_stop = Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop,width=10)
b_stop.pack(padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

**Changes:**

- A while loop might cause the window to become unresponsive, hence ive used `after()` method here to repeat a function constantly, if you have any plans of cancelling the `after()` calls, let me know. You can adjust the time between each call by adjusting `ms`.
- Here I have also used `randint` instead of `randrange()` hope it serves the same purpose for this need too.
- And also i have removed the import of `tkinter.font` as there is no need to import a module and can specify the fonts in tuple like `("calibri",30,"bold")`

**Why use `after()` and not `while`?**

This is because a `while` loop might interfere a tkinter `mainloop()` causing the window to be unresponsive at times, so it is not recommended to use `while` or `time.sleep()`. Instead you could use the built-in `after()` method by tkinter or `threading` too.

**Here is a bit more on `after()`:**

- It takes two positional arguments,mainly, `ms` and `func`
- `ms` - It is the time(in milliseconds) after which the specified function will be triggered.
- `func` - It is the function to be triggered after the specified `ms` finishes.

Hope this cleares your doubts, do let me know if any errors.

Cheers

Comment: @Maria and if your planning to end the `after()` let me know.

Comment: I would to do with start button I think it will be sth like state false and True

Comment: And paue and stop buttons

Comment: Look what I built so far thanks to you I'm planing to do cardiomonitor simulator

Comment: @Maria It looks cool! Do you mind on removing the image, becuase its not recommended to update questions with received answers or image.

Comment: @Maria All the best :)